# Node.js API with express & mysql - Redefine fetched parameters for correct column search

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, express

In my url I want to be able to search column 'active' and 'last_name' ... with the parameters:

```
active
name
```

like this:

```
localhost:4001/api/v1/users/?active=1&name=Peter
```

users.js

```
var sql = "SELECT * from users";
var existingParams = ["active", "name"].filter(field => req.query[field]);

if (existingParams.length !== 0) { 
    sql += ' WHERE ';
    sql += existingParams.map(field => `${field} = ?`).join(" AND ");
}
```

... provides me this:

```
SELECT * from users WHERE active = ? AND name = ? LIMIT 100
```

I'm getting an error though ... since the column name in the database is defined 'last_name' ... so I want to end up with sth like this:

```
SELECT * from users WHERE active = ? AND last_name = ? LIMIT 100
```

... but keep the search parameter in the url 'name'. How co I need to alter my script?

Comment: query.last_name  = query.name add last_name key manually.

Comment: ... but the .map(field => `${field} = ?`) defines the column to search in. It searches in a non existing column. The values are correct

Comment: after adding  `delete query.name` and change `["active", "last_name"]`

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: remove key from req.query

Comment: I just don't know what you mean by 'delete query.name and change ["active", "last_name"]'. Can you show me?

Comment: you need to do `delete req.query.name;
var existingParams = ["active", "last_name"].filter(field => req.query[field]);`

Comment: That didn't work. ... that leads to returning all the results. console.log(sql) provides me ... SELECT * from users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
existingParams.map(field => {
  if (field === 'name') {
    field = 'last_name'
  }
  return `${field} = ?`
}).join(" AND ");
```

try this and let me know